# the height and space for div if the children element is button

Tags: css

I would like to set the div exactly matching the button.(no space between the button and div)

As far as I know, the height for div should depend on the children elements.

I put a button into div and set the height 22px for the button.

but the height for the div is 24.13px and is not the same as the height for the button.

[image]

I have set ***box-sizing: border-box, the margin and padding 0***

would anyone tell me the reason why and how to fix this problem?

html code

```
<div>
<button>123</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

button{
height:22px;
}
```

thanks!!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code using the code snippet icon so people can see what the problem is

Comment: @Adam,hi, is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a css rule that's putting padding-top on your element. If I recreate it on the code snippet editor you'll see there's no padding (I've put a border round the div so you can see that the div is tight up against the button). You'll need to post more of your css. Are you using a framework like bootstrap?

I'll edit this answer with if you can post an example that reproduces the problem you're experiencing.

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

button{
height:22px;
}

div {
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>123</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for answering my question,I'm not using any css framework.
the code snippet you show, yes, there's no padding on it  based on dev tools.
but the height for the button is 22px and the div is 25.75px.
if you zoom in there, you will find that there're some white space on button's top but nothing on button's left and bottom.
it's still the same, even though I type the same code in a online code editor(codepen).
my browser is Edge.

Comment: Can you post a link to the codepen you're using please? I'll have a look in edge. What version of edge are you using?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vergil-chan/pen/mdLyOZE
version for my Edge is 105.0.1343.27
thx!